# How to run PowerShell script using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start in c#?

Tags: c#, powershell, execute, system.diagnostics

I'm writing this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
Process.Start("C:\\CodeProjects\\C#\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell_ise.exe", "-File .\\mp4_to_flac.ps1");
```

All this does is *open* up the script in Windows PowerShell ISE. But I *also want it to RUN!* So what other arguments do I have to pass in so that it executes?

[Process.Start method Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h6ak8zt5)

Comment: Any reason why you are using powershell_ise.exe and not powershell.exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to run powershell_ise.exe but powershell.exe.  From a dos command prompt you can just prefix your command or script with @powershell, but for a process you're going to want to use something like

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

(that's mine on Win 8.1), yours should be somewhere near there if you're on a different version.

The [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) guys throw in these switches

```
-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
```

when executing powershell from the command prompt, you might have to do that also depending on how your execution policy is set.

Comment: so simple! thanks, i just took out "_ise" from my code. It executes instead of opening powershell ISE. Great. :)

Comment: any idea why running PS script using process doesn't load all the modules ?
my script contains `Import-Module ServerManager` which runs fine when manually executed, but from process it fails `Import-Module : The specified module \ServerManager was not loaded no valid module file was found`

Answer (score -1):

You could call it like so:

```
Process.Start(".\\mp4_to_flac.ps1");
```

and make sure all your windows settings are correct, so a double click on the file will execute it.

Comment: Double-clicking on .ps1 will open it for edit with the correct default settings. This is a security measure.

Comment: On my machine I changed the setting so double click will execute the .ps1. With this setting the approach in my answer will work.

Comment: I personally do not consider that helpful, because not everyone is willing to change default global (secure) settings to non-default and less secure so that a single program could work.

Comment: @DrKoch, how did you change your setting to execute .ps1 with powershell?